# Is it best practice to execute a Go program with go run code.go for actual use?

Tags: go, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I have a CI/CD pipeline that needs to be cross-platform and work with several different hypervisors. In order to not have to change up the build tasks for Windows and Linux, I was thinking Go would be a great way to write the code once and run anywhere. A conundrum comes in to play given Go creates executables, however - my CI/CD platform has no way to pull in an exe or binary at build time to run the builds steps "normally" via Go. I was thinking I could just commit the Go code with the project and use:

```
go run build_step.go
```

For each build task, but I'm wondering if that's an acceptable practice/use case. I know it will work, just wondering if there's a better way to do this. I'm using Azure DevOps Pipelines for what it's worth.

Comment: `go run` is a toy. [It changes the semantics of exit codes](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13440), for instance. If you can execute `go run` you can also execute `go build` or `go install`.

Comment: So would your advice for this use case then be to chain go build and go install together?

Comment: `go install` already runs `go build`. If you want your binary installed to `$GOPATH/bin`, use `go install`. If you want it output anywhere else, use `go build`.

Comment: Just for you want a cross-platform CI/CD, what about considering to use [strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#strategies) in YAML to achieve it? Like **matrix** could run different platform with different copies of job. This do not need you change up the build for windows or linux, just configure them at same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cross build. example :

GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 go build -o build.exe build_step.go

or

GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm go build -o build build_step.go