# Why reflect.ValueOf() gives different output in called function and calling function in golang?

Tags: go

Why the outputs of s and s1 differs although the starting value is same ? Help me understand

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Auth struct {
    a, b interface{}
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("--------p1,s1--------")
    p1 := Auth{}
    fmt.Println(p1)
    s1 := reflect.ValueOf(p1)
    fmt.Println(s1)

    fmt.Println("-------s---------")
    callFunc(p1)

}

func callFunc(a ...interface{}) {
    s := reflect.ValueOf(a)
    fmt.Println(s)

}
```

Ps. Filename is nil.go
On running the code using :go run nil.go
The output is :

[image]

Comment: `a` is a variadic argument type, so its a slice of interface{}

Comment: Also, not relevant here, but: never use `go run`.

Comment: @torek y not to use go run ? Just curious

Comment: @AyushRaj: See [Peter's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59968053/is-it-best-practice-to-execute-a-go-program-with-go-run-code-go-for-actual-use#comment106053117_59968053) on [Is it best practice to execute a Go program with go run code.go for actual use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59968053/1256452), which links to a discussion that includes [this comment from Dave Cheney](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13440#issuecomment-218352852).

Comment: Besides messing with exit codes, `go run` also messes with signal handling, since there's now an "outer" program monitoring the compiled program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`fmt`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt) package documents that when printing `reflect.Value` values, it prints the value wrapped inside them:

> Except when printed using the verbs %T and %p, special formatting considerations apply for operands that implement certain interfaces. In order of application:
>
> 1. If the operand is a reflect.Value, the operand is replaced by the concrete value that it holds, and printing continues with the next rule.
>
> [...]

`callFunc()` has a variadic parameter:

```
func callFunc(a ...interface{})
```

This means `a` is a *slice*. So when printing `reflect.ValueOf(a)`, you'll get the slice printed. And the `fmt` package also documents that:

> For compound objects, the elements are printed using these rules, recursively, laid out like this:
>
> ```
> struct:             {field0 field1 ...}
> array, slice:       [elem0 elem1 ...]
> maps:               map[key1:value1 key2:value2 ...]
> pointer to above:   &{}, &[], &map[]
> ```

Slices are printed enclosed in square brackets.

Note that if `callFunc()` would not be variadic:

```
func callFunc(a interface{}) {
    s := reflect.ValueOf(a)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Then output would be the same (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/FDkZihhSYxz)):

```
--------p1,s1--------
{<nil> <nil>}
{<nil> <nil>}
-------s---------
{<nil> <nil>}
```